# Manipulating displayed views in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

I'm trying to implement a `ListView` subclass on Android that allows its contents to be manually reordered.  As the first step in that process, I'm attaching a 'long-click' listener to each child view that the `ListView` draws, like:

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {

    //listen for long-click events as the trigger for reordering the list
    child.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (! SortableListView.this.isSortEnabled()) {
                return false;
            }

            //capture some state about the initial position of the list
            //[...]

            //note the view that we're moving around
            dragView = view;
            dragView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(128, 200, 200, 255));
            dragView.setElevation(2.0f);

            //disable the list's default scrolling behavior
            SortableListView.this.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            return true;
        }
    });

    //also add a general touch listener for when we're actually sorting things
    child.setOnTouchListener(this);

    return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
}
```

And then there's also a general 'touch' event listener to handle updates to the `ListView` once we're actually dragging something:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    //XXX:  (0,0) is at the top-left of the screen
    if (dragView == null) {
        //not dragging anything yet, just note the touch location for if/when we start
        dragStartX = motionEvent.getRawX();
        dragStartY = motionEvent.getRawY();

        return false;
    }
    if (view != dragView) {
        //not interested in this event
        return false;
    }

    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        dragCurrentX = motionEvent.getRawX();
        dragCurrentY = motionEvent.getRawY();

        //make the cell the user tapped follow their touch
        dragView.animate().xBy(dragCurrentX - dragStartX).yBy(dragCurrentY - dragStartY).setDuration(0).start();

        //now look at how far the view has moved, and reposition the displayed views if necessary (this is the broken part)
        //[...]

        return true;
    }
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //done, put the view back
        dragView.setTranslationX(0);
        dragView.setTranslationY(0);
        dragView.setElevation(0.0f);
        dragView = null;

        //enable scrolling
        this.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The issue is that while dragging the view around generally works, I also want to shift its "placeholder" spot up/down behind it as it moves.  Perhaps it's best to illustrate this with some photos:

**Initial State**
[image: Initial State]

**After Starting to Drag**
[image: After starting to drag]

**After Dragging a Bit**
[image]

So the goal is to have the "placeholder" cell follow the floating blue cell as the user drags it through the list.  I'm trying to accomplish this by manipulating the list's subviews as the floating cell moves, but so far nothing is working.

My current code (i.e "the broken part") for attempting this is:

```
int dragViewIndex = this.indexOfChild(dragView);
if (dragView.getTranslationY() > dragView.getHeight() && dragViewIndex < this.getChildCount() - 1) {
    //move down 1 spot (towards bottom of list), reduce tY by height
    this.detachViewFromParent(dragView);
    this.attachViewToParent(dragView, dragViewIndex + 1, dragView.getLayoutParams());

    dragView.setTranslationY(dragView.getTranslationY() - dragView.getHeight());
}
if (dragView.getTranslationY() < -1 * dragView.getHeight() && dragViewIndex > 0) {
    //move up 1 spot (towards top of list), reduce tY by height
    this.detachViewFromParent(dragView);
    this.attachViewToParent(dragView, dragViewIndex - 1, dragView.getLayoutParams());

    dragView.setTranslationY(dragView.getTranslationY() + dragView.getHeight());
}
```

But that seems to accomplish almost nothing (apart from confusing the list; as you can see in the third picture, where the entry being dragged actually appears *twice* in the UI).

Is there a proper/elegant way to get the empty cell to follow the content around through the list?  Or do I need to look at more drastic measures, like maybe translating every *other* cell in the list to accommodate where the empty space is meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was on the right track with the idea about translating the other cells in the list.  This code does what I want:

```
if (dragView.getTranslationY() - dragView.getHeight() * numShifts > dragView.getHeight() && dragViewIndex < this.getChildCount() - 1) {
    //move down 1 spot (towards bottom of list)
    View displacedView = this.getChildAt(dragViewIndex + 1);
    if (displacedView.getTranslationY() != 0) {
        displacedView = this.getChildAt(dragViewIndex);
        displacedView.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(100).start();
    }
    else {
        displacedView.animate().yBy(-1 * view.getHeight()).setDuration(100).start();
    }
    dragViewIndex++;
    numShifts++;
}
else if (dragView.getTranslationY() - dragView.getHeight() * numShifts < -1 * dragView.getHeight() && dragViewIndex > 0) {
    //move up 1 spot (towards top of list)
    View displacedView = this.getChildAt(dragViewIndex - 1);
    if (displacedView.getTranslationY() != 0) {
        displacedView = this.getChildAt(dragViewIndex);
        displacedView.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(100).start();
    }
    else {
        displacedView.animate().yBy(view.getHeight()).setDuration(100).start();
    }
    dragViewIndex--;
    numShifts--;
}
```

Could probably be cleaned up a bit.  But basically you watch how far the cell has been dragged, and each time it moves up/down a full increment (based upon its height) you shift the cell underneath it up/down as appropriate.  This creates the appearance of the "placeholder" cell moving around in the list.

Note that **this code only works if every item in the list has the same height**.  Which is good enough for my use-case, but not for every use-case.